# Adding a bar legend to a 3D plot indicating surface curvature by color

Tags: plotting, color, legending, differential-geometry

I want to color surfaces according to its Gaussian curvature, but the color bar is not consistent with the color.

How can I improve it?

Color a HyperbolicParaboloid according to its Gaussian curvature:

```
{surf, gaucurv} = 
Through[SurfaceData[
"HyperbolicParaboloid", {"ParametricEquations", 
"GaussianCurvature"}][3, 4]];
rng = {NMinValue[{gaucurv[u, v], -5 <= u <= 5 && -5 <= v <= 5}, 
{u, v}], NMaxValue[{gaucurv[u, v], -5 <= u <= 5 && -5 <= v <= 5}, 
{u, v}]};
ParametricPlot3D[surf[u, v], {u, -5, 5}, {v, -5, 5}, 
ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, 
ColorData["Rainbow"]@Rescale[gaucurv[u, v], rng]], 
ColorFunctionScaling -> False, MeshStyle -> Opacity[0.25], 
PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"Rainbow", rng}], Boxed -> False, 
Axes -> False, Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}]
```

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SurfaceData.html

[image: Gaussian curvature]

Comment: try using `PlotLegends -> 
 BarLegend[{"Rainbow", rng}, ColorFunctionScaling -> True]`?

Comment: @kglr . I just tried it, but it didn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"Rainbow", rng}]` with

```
PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{ColorData[{"Rainbow", rng}], rng}]
```

or with

```
PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"Rainbow", rng}, Method -> ColorFunctionScaling -> True]
```

to get the correct colors in the legend:

```
ParametricPlot3D[surf[u, v], {u, -5, 5}, {v, -5, 5}, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, 
    ColorData["Rainbow"]@Rescale[gaucurv[u, v], rng]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 MeshStyle -> Opacity[0.25], 
 Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{ColorData[{"Rainbow", rng}], rng}]], 
 Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}]
```

[image]

```
ParametricPlot3D[surf[u, v], {u, -5, 5}, {v, -5, 5}, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, 
    ColorData["Rainbow"]@Rescale[gaucurv[u, v], rng]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 MeshStyle -> Opacity[0.25], 
 Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"Rainbow", rng}, ColorFunctionScaling -> True], 
 Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}]
```

> same picture

A third approach is to move the legend outside `ParametricPlot3D` using `Legended` as in m_goldberg's answer:

```
Legended[ParametricPlot3D[surf[u, v], {u, -5, 5}, {v, -5, 5}, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, 
    ColorData["Rainbow"]@Rescale[gaucurv[u, v], rng]], 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, MeshStyle -> Opacity[0.25], 
  Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}], 
 BarLegend[{"Rainbow", rng}]]
```

> same picture

All three methods work both in Version 11.3 (Windows 10 6 bit) and Version 12.0 (Wolfram Cloud).

Answer (score 6):

Here is another way. It gives a finer scale on the bar legend.

```
Legended[
  ParametricPlot3D[surf[u, v], {u, -5, 5}, {v, -5, 5},
    ColorFunction ->
      Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, ColorData["Rainbow"] @ Rescale[gaucurv[u, v], rng]], 
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
    MeshStyle -> Opacity[0.25],
    Boxed -> False,
    Axes -> False,
    Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}],
  BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {Floor[rng[[1]], .01], Ceiling[rng[[2]], .01]}}, 9]]
```

[image: plot]